# Environment.NewLine logic does not start text on a new line in HTML

Tags: c#, newline, stringbuilder, environment

I saw a few similar questions, but could not find the answer related to what I need to do.

I want to format my string to be display on a javascript popup with each entry on a new line. So, I'm doing the following logic:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
_checkRangeError = _checkRangeError + "#" + value1 + "#" + value2 + "#" + value3;
sb.Append(_checkRangeError).Replace("#", Environment.NewLine);
lblAddError.Text = sb.ToString();
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Validation Error", "ValidateRangeOnAdd();", true);
```

When executing it, the values are displayed on the same line.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Presuming that in JavaScript you are outputting HTML, newlines characters are ignored unless inside specific tags.  Try using `<br />` instead

Comment: What is `lblAddError`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Thank you. That's exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

When outputting HTML `Environment.NewLine` and `"\n"` don't have any visible effect in the browser. You have to use a `<br />` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

in c# `Environment.NewLine` is equals to  `\r\n`. 
if you want to display your text in javascript or html you need to replace `\r\n` with `<br />`
 
 so try to replace :

```
lblAddError.Text = sb.ToString();
```

with

```
lblAddError.Text = sb.ToString().Replace("\r\n" , "<br />");
```